# Getting git metadata from git_repository rule

Tags: bazel

Prior to [this](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/e39991acbeb5c5cacbb61de004be77436be3664e#diff-837a9f01631c2638001dbb9c581868ad) commit (first included in 0.17.0), I was able to use a `genrule` to gather git metadata from external git repositories.

It effectively looked like this:

```
genrule(
  name = "git-describe-foo",
  # We can't dep all of @foo, so we pick a file
  srcs = ["@foo//:SOME_FILE"],
  outs = ["my_version"],
  # Do a git describe and strip off the leading "v"
  cmd = "git -C $$(dirname $(location @foo//:SOME_FILE)) describe --tags | cut -c 2- > $@",
  # I don't know if this is strictly necessary
  stamp = True,
  # This is required or bazel will sandbox us with just SOME_FILE
  local = True,
  output_to_bindir = True,
)
```

However, this no longer works because the `.git/` directory has now been removed. I understand that this was done to improve reproducibility, but the git SHA (and theoretically the git history) should actually not affect the reproducibility of builds.

My original approach was to try to pass in the git SHA and git metadata that I needed via `--workspace_status_command` somehow, but then i'd also have to use that git SHA to clone the `git_repository`, which I don't think is possible.

Is there another way to gather this information?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour and read through the help center, in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers!

Comment: @JonathanGagne hmm. not sure where I went wrong. The bazel community generally wants people to ask questions on Stack Overflow using the bazel tag. I think a bazel expert would know exactly the problem that I am hitting given my example genrule. Perhaps this would be better suited for a GitHub issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your use of the `genrule` is generally broken, as it depends on more than the declared inputs. As you noticed yourself, sandboxing detects these undeclared (and hence untracked by `bazel`) inputs.

The reason why the `.git` subdirectory is deleted as part of the `git_repository` rule is to have reproducible content of the external repository in a [machine-verifiable form](https://github.com/bazelbuild/proposals/blob/master/designs/2018-07-13-repository-hashing.md). However, all parts of the repository rule, including the `patch_cmds` are executed before the `.git` subdirectory is removed. So you can create meta data as part of the repository itself, e.g., as follows.

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:git.bzl", "git_repository")

git_repository(
  remote = "...",
  ...
  patch_cmds = [
    "git log -n 1 --format=%H > VERSION",
  ],
)
```

There are two things to keep in mind.

- To be reproducible, the meta data should be fully determined by the commit itself.
- Make sure that the that the added meta-data file is exported, e.g., by patching `exports_files(["VERSION"])` into the `BUILD` file of the external repository.